# PDF in aspose made is not showing chinese characters

Tags: package, aspose

I am using aspose.total package for pdf generation. The reports are generated fine for english language some characters in chinese language are not coming fine. I have found that instead of showing characters its showing square like image. Does any one know how to deal with this ?

Thanks,

Comment: A few things come to mind: are you using the correct font? Are you using the correct encoding? Are you embedding fonts? Please edit your question and add some details. Furthermore, adding some source code how you're creating the pdf would help.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that Aspose.Words requires TrueType fonts when rendering documents to fixed-page formats (JPEG, PNG, PDF or XPS). You need to install fonts that are used in your document on the machine where you're converting documents to Pdf. Please refer to the following articles:

[How Aspose.Words Uses True Type Fonts](https://docs.aspose.com//display/wordsnet/True+Type+Fonts#TrueTypeFonts-HowAspose.WordsUsesTrueTypeFonts)

I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the font as follow:

```
TextFragment textFragment = new TextFragment("text");
 textFragment.TextState.Font = FontRepository.OpenFont("C:\\WINDOWS\\FONTS\\SIMHEI.TTF");
```